# Tunnel using python sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to replicate the commands

```
ssh -L8080:127.0.0.1:80 example.com
```

and

```
ssh -R8080:127.0.0.1:80 example.com
```

using the python library `sshtunnel` (https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/).

So I have figured out the equivalent of

```
ssh -L8080:127.0.0.1:80 example.com
```

to be

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
'example.com',
ssh_username="username",
ssh_password="password",
remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080))
```

But I am still unable to understand how to replicate the command

```
ssh -R8080:127.0.0.1:80 example.com
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add some details to your question? What is going wrong? Please post also your error messages or log file entries here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a bit more detail

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use subprocess and run the command in shell?

```
for example:

import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["YOUR_COMMAND"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

This is an advice, depend as well what you need do with it if only run the command or you need do extra operation!

Comment: This isn't what OP asked for, the question is very specifically about a module

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you might have confused the remote and local port.

Try something like:

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
'example.com',
ssh_username="username",
ssh_password="password",
local_bind_address=('', 8080),
remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 80))
```

If you want to share your remote 80 port to all your interfaces.

Or it may be better to use:

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
'example.com',
ssh_username="username",
ssh_password="password",
local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080),
remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 80))
```

To share only for the local interface.